# block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I'm using spring boot version '2.4.5' and 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'. When I try to execute the code below, I get the following error `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-5`
I tried to use toFuture() and share() methods, but they didn't work.

```
    String Student = webClient.get()
            .uri("MY_URL")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Student.class)
            .block();
    
    boolean isValid = verifyStudentInfo(student);
    
    if (isValid) {
        method1();
    } else {
        method2();
    }
```

In my case, I need the operation to be blocking because I will be using the result later in the code. I didn't want to use RestTemplate because it will be deprecated and I already have WebClient configuration in my project including ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository.

Is there anyway I can enable blocking operations?

Comment: it depends, if you are writing a pure webflux application then blocking is very very bad for performance, and you get the exception because it is not allowed. `I need the operation to be blocking because I will be using the result later in the code` could you please update your code to elaborate on this statement, why do you need the result later. We need more context to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Its still very little context, plese put in some effort if you expect us to do the same, which means my answer will be very short. Use the `flatMap` function, if you dont know what that means i suggest you read the reactor documentation since  `flatMap` is the absolut basic of reactive programming.

Comment: the important question is, as @Toerktumlare asked before, "is this a purely webflux application?" If so, you should not be blocking ever.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen This is actually not a purely webflux application. I need both blocking and non-blocking. But instead of using RestTemplate for blocking, I wanted to use WebClient because I already have the WebClient configuration and RestTemplate will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: @MA1 thanks for responding. It may be helpful to add that piece of information into the question.

Comment: I believe you can use `.toFuture().get()` instead of .`block()`

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen When I use `.toFuture().get()`, the application gets stuck at that line of code and never execute the next line (something similar to the infinite loop)

Comment: maybe you have an issue where your `Mono` is never emitting a value causing the `Future` to never complete. You can pass in a timeout into the `get()` method ie. `.toFuture().get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

Answer (score 0):

Reactive apis/processes are not supposed to operate outside the publisher pipelines which are to be subscribed by the client or the browser. If you need to access a publisher's data in your api, you can use flatMap to integrate it in your publisher pipeline and drive your business logic with this which will be executed after the client subscribes to the publisher.

You can use something like this if you want to use an integer value to drive your business logic

```
    Mono<Void> useValFromMono() {
        return getMono().flatMap(valFromMono -> getPublisherBasedOnVal(valFromMono));
    }

    Mono<Integer> getMono() {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> getInteger());
    }

    private Integer getInteger() {
        return new Random().nextInt(10);
    }

    Mono<Void> getPublisherBasedOnVal(Integer integer) {
        if(integer == 2) {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("Its 2!"));
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

In your case you could do

```
  return webClient.get()
           .uri("MY_URL")
           .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           .retrieve()
           .bodyToMono(Student.class)
           .flatMap(student -> verifyStudentInfo(student) ? Mono.fromRunnable(() -> method1()) : Mono.fromRunnable((() -> method2())));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you code is called from some WebFlux controller and there is no reason to block here. You could just continue the flow and return `Mono<T>` from the controller.

Consider something like

```
Mono<Student> getStudent() {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("MY_URL")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Student.class)
            .map(student -> {
                boolean isValid = verifyStudentInfo(student);
                if (isValid) {
                    return method1();
                } else {
                    return method2();
                }
            });
```

Some people suggested `toFuture().get()` but it is technically the same as `block()`. It will not result in exception `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread ...` because it's out of Reactor API control but problem is still the same because this operation is blocking and you just hide the issue.

If you really need to call blocking code (for example, some legacy code that is still using `RestTemplate`) from the reactive flow, wrap it into `Runnable` or `Callable` and schedule on a separate `Scheduler`. Check [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#faq.wrap-blocking) for details.